Set reference in HTML file to copied file in docker
I copy the logo to my container defining the following part in my Dockerfile.
COPY ./frontend/src/assets/my_logo.png frontend/my_logo.png

Here my whole dockerfile
FROM  eclipse-temurin:17.0.8.1_1-jre
COPY ./frontend/src/assets/my_logo.png frontend/my_logo.png
COPY ./src/main/resources/application.yaml frontend/application.yaml
COPY ./target/myApp.jar myApp.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dspring.config.location=/frontend/application.yaml" ,"-jar", "myApp.jar"]

I deploy my angular with spring boot.
I can see that the file was copied to frontend/my_logo.png starting the container (-p 8090:8080 --hostname frontendTest).
Now, I want to use my_logo.png in my HTML.
 <img
        class="my-class"
        alt="alt"
        src="http://localhost:8090/frontend/my_logo.png"
      />

I also tried the following options
src="/frontend/my_logo.png"
src="frontendTest/frontend/my_logo.png"

How can I set the right src to get my copied file?

That depends on what web server you use to serve the files and how it is setup.

Where are the rest of your HTML files in the container filesystem?  It's as likely as not just <img src="my_logo.png">.

I have edited my question to answer yours

I have solved my problem. It is not neccessary copying my_logo.png into the container.
I can get my_logo.png with "http://localhost:8090/assets/my_logo.png". This is because I put my angular-app including the assets-folder into my Spring-App. So in the case you are running your angular in Spring, you can reach the content of your assets this way.
But the question why I can´t access the copied file is still open.
